# How to remove spaces & brackets from a phone number with Regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I remove spaces and brackets from a phone number according to the following example with Regular Expressions?

Input: `+7(999) 999 99 99`
Output: `+79999999999`

I tried the following code, but it didn't work for me:

```js
const phone = "+7(999) 999 99 99";
phone.replace(/\s/g, "");
```

Comment: What do you mean *"dont working"*? It removes the spaces for me, assuming the input is actually a string `"+7(999) 999 99 99"`.

Comment: The regular expression will do what you're asking for in the title but not what you're asking for in the body of your question.

Comment: Why don't you try getting the number and `+` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As other people said in the comments, **your provided regular expression will remove the spaces for you** but **if you want to remove parentheses as well you need another regex for that**. **Keep in mind [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method will return a new string** so in order to get the new value and use it you should assign it to a new variable.

So your code should something like this:

```js
const phone = '+7(999) 999 99 99'

let newPhone = phone.replace(/\s/g, '').replace(/[()]/g, '')

console.log(newPhone)

// or simply do this with one replace:

newPhone = phone.replace(/[()\s]/g, '')

console.log(newPhone)
```

Comment: Why two `.replace()` calls? Just combine the regular expressions into one.

Comment: @Andreas Yeah, you are totally right but I just did this for more illustration.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const phone = '+7(999) 999 99 99';
console.log(phone.replace(/\(|\)/g, "").replace(/\s/g, ''));
```

I think this will help you!